# Edited value in CSV file not importing correctly

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am taking the needed line from a text file containing lots of records. The following is an example:

```
2021-01-30,14:08,16.3544,
```

My code:

```py
     with open('report.txt', 'r') as in_file:
            stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file) 
            lines = (line.split(',') for line in stripped if line)
            lines = in_file.read().splitlines()
            last_line = lines[-3]
            print (last_line)
            with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
                writer = csv.writer(out_file)
                writer.writerow(('date', 'time','val'))
                writer.writerows(last_line)
```

Every time I put the values in the CSV file, and try to imported it, it is not done correctly. Every number is in a separate cell, see the inline picture:

[image: csv-file]

Comment: What is the output that comes into the console from the print(last_line) procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you simply got a bit lost in the lines and trying to get it work. I took the liberty of renaming a few things, and using the `writerow` method, in instead of `writerows`.

```py
with open('report.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in in_file]
    records = [line.split(',') for line in lines if line != ""]
    last = records[-1]
    with open('/tmp/log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('date', 'time','val'))
        writer.writerow(last)
```

The code might be not exactly what you need, but at least it writes the record correctly.
The problem you were experiencing is that `writerows` was writing `2,0,2,0,-..` to your file, since you were passing a tuple of tuples.

The above would create a file, which would import probably like you want:

```
date,time,val
2021-01-30,14:08,16.3544,
```

If you want to write all records back (after updating them), you can do `writer.writerows(records)`.